# Javascript cannot reach element loaded with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I load div with PHP and then I want to get it from HTML using Javascript. Getting element by id alerts `undefined`.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
   <?php echo "<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>" ?>
     <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        alert( $("#myDiv").html())
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

How is that even possible?

Comment: I edited my question, see code. It still does not work. And it is weird that php question mark is shown after hello.

Comment: (0) What are you serving the page with? and (1) what's the extension of the file in question? (2) Is it intentional to omit the `body` tag from this document?

Comment: If you're seeing the `?>` output to the HTML it means the PHP isn't being interpreted. This can be confirmed by viewing source in the browser. If you see the PHP code in the output, this is your issue. Most likely because you've given the file a `.html` extension instead of `.php`. Change that and the code should work fine.

Comment: My file format is .php. I ust wanted to insert it like html for better understanding and ability to run it like code snippet on stackoverflow

Comment: Please keep the script and php code inside the <body> tag and test

Answer (score 1):

You have saved the file with a `.htm` extension. Change it to `.php` and the code works as expected.

With HTML

`<?php echo "<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>" ?>`

is interpreted as:

```
<?php echo "<div id='myDiv'>
Hello
</div>
" ?>
```

with lines 1 and 3 seen as tags, and the other two as output.

Comment: Yes, my file originaly is .php file. My main problem is that I cannot reach my div by id with javascript after it is loaded with php

Comment: It won't load into the SE snippet, or in ay php playground as it isn't pure PHP, but it should run from your server.

Answer (score 0):

The following code exists inside "c:\xampp\htdocs\snippets\nov21\something.php" and when requested as `localhost/snippets/nov21/something.php` (the web-root directory is c:\xampp\htdocs\ ), performs the action you've mentioned.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    alert( document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo("<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Viewing the page-source in the browser returns the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);
function onLoaded(evt)
{
    alert( document.querySelector('#myDiv').innerHTML );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='myDiv'>Hello</div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[PHP](https://www.php.net/) is a serverside language, it is rendered serverside. This means it won't render if you just open a `.php` file with a web browser and it won't work if you try to run the code in an online editor. It needs to be hosted by a web server and then the sever renders it when requested.

**How is that even possible?** Becuase the php is never rendered, therefore the `<div>` doesn't exist.

That being said, a few other notes:

) php goes in the `<body></body>` section of your html

) you can put the `<script>`s at the bottom of the body section and than you don't need to use `$(document).ready()`, since if you're at the bottom of the `<body>`, the document is ready...

This won't work in an online editor, but you code should look something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php echo "<div id='myDiv'>Hello</div>"; ?>
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      alert($("#myDiv").html());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```